# Customized x-axis matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just want to use a list of decimal years to assign the labels and ticks for a customized x-axis:

```
labels = [1992.71, 1991.67, 1990.5, 1989.54, 1988.5, 1987.5, .., 1700.5]
```

IMPORTANT: The interval between 2 consecutive values in the above list is not constant, I only care about steps here, so every position in the list should be a tick or a bin.

The problem is that if I use all the labels in the list, the graph gets too dense. By the way, inside my graph lies a PNG image, not a plot.

So, I have decided (maybe wrongly) to generate a second list with only the values I need (this time using strings):

```
labels2 = ['1992.71','','','','','1987.50', etc.]
```

Ideally, I would like the x-axis to have either this configuration:

[image: selected labels in the right bin number and no ticks]

or this one:

[image: selected labels and associated ticks in the right bin number, no other ticks]

or this one:

[image: selected labels and associated ticks at the start of the bin; left]

So far I have been playing with these functions:

```
ax.set_xticklabels
plt.locator_params
ax.tick_params
plt.xticks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter
...
```

with no success.

This is the closest I have been:

[image]

But the sequence of labels gets CUT in the right hand-side of the x-axis and never reaches the end of the list, so it finishes half-way through the list (which should end in 1700.5):

[image]

Also, I just want to display the ticks corresponding to the selected labels and not all of them.

this is my code:

```
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=len(labels2)-1)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels2, rotation=90 )
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', length=4, labelsize=2)
```

In essence, currently I cannot reproduced what I want to,

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the tick locations using `set_xticks` and then set the labels using `set_xticklabels` with an array of the same length. If you don't want to label each tick then set fewer ticks and labels as in the right subplot. **Make sure the number of labels always equals the number of ticks set**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(matplotlib.__file__), 'mpl-data/sample_data/Minduka_Present_Blue_Pack.png')
img = mpimg.imread(file)
labels = [1992.71, 1991.67, 1990.5, 1989.54, 1988.5, 1987.5, 1980.1, 1700.5]

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax1.imshow(img)
ax1.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, img.shape[1], len(labels)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation = 90)

ax2.imshow(img)
ax2.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, img.shape[1], len(labels))[::2])
ax2.set_xticklabels(labels[::2], rotation = 90)
```

[image]